# Unexpected error with aggregate query to Azure Cosmos DB via MongoAPI

Tags: azure, aggregation-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I've noticed that aggregate query fails on my db:

```
{ 
  "aggregate" : "visitors", 
  "pipeline" : [
     { "$match" : { "project" : "E2E120AF-AC50-4969-9DA1-CFA1E31D7E17", "data.lastVisit" : { "$gt" : ISODate("2018-02-07T17:00:00Z") } } },
     { "$group" : { "_id" : { "$hour" : "$data.lastVisit" }, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
   ]
}
```

I tried this both from `MongoChef` and `.Net client` app and everywhere I get `unexpected error` as a result:

```
{{ "_t" : "OKMongoResponse", "ok" : 0, "code" : 1, "errmsg" : "unexpected error occured while processing the request", "$err" : "unexpected error occured while processing the request" }}
```

If I use other date expression operator like `$dayOfYear`, it fails as well. If I do grouping by `data.lastVisit` without any date expression it works fine. Of course same query works smoothly on real MongoDB.

Documents structure in `visitors` collection is like this:

```
{ 
    "project" : "E2E120AF-AC50-4969-9DA1-CFA1E31D7E17", 
    "data" : {
        "defaultName" : true, 
        "name" : "...", 
        "geo" : {
            ...
        }, 
        "firstVisit" : ISODate("2018-02-21T09:10:06.464+0000"), 
        "ip" : "....", 
        "lastVisit" : ISODate("2018-02-21T09:10:08.582+0000")
    }, 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a8d376ef72db1002b9c591a"), 
    "sockets" : [
    ], 
    "isBlacklisted" : false, 
    "online" : true
}
```

I believe it's an issue in Cosmos DB realization of aggregate pipeline, so any workarounds and information on how to file a Cosmos DB issue would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've managed to find a workaround for that which is one have to simply add the field to grouping `_id`:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : { time: { "$hour" : "$data.lastVisit" } }, "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
```

But the error is still there and it's definitely an issue.